# Passing output of custom bazel rule to a *_binary rule as runtime data

Tags: bazel

I have a rule that creates a folder (untars a tar.gz) and I would like to use this folder directly as data for a cc_binary. The only way I could find to so is to create an intermediate filegroup with the created folder as source.

Though it works it requires the users of the rule to create an intermediate filegroup and introduces some naming issues as the name of the filegroup cannot be the same as the created folder name.

This is what I have

```
# rules.bzl
def _untar_impl(ctx):
    tree = ctx.actions.declare_directory(ctx.attr.out)
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        inputs = [ctx.file.src],
        outputs = [tree],
        command = "tar -C '{out}' -xf '{src}'".format(src=ctx.file.src.path, out=tree.path),
    )

    return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([tree]))]

untar = rule(
    implementation = _untar_impl,
    attrs = {
        "src": attr.label(mandatory=True, allow_single_file = True),
        "out": attr.string(mandatory=True),
    },
)

# BUILD
untar(
    name = "media",
    src = "media.tar.gz",
    out = "media",
)

filegroup(
    name = "mediafiles",
    srcs = ["media"],
    data = [":media"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    data = [":mediafiles"],
)
```

Is there any way to avoid having the intermediate filegroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion that ensued, I see I've misunderstood the problem statement a bit. You probably still want to look into handling that tarball (and its entire processing) as an external dependency and a `repository_rule`, but for your immediate problem of need of intermediate `filegroup`.

If you noticed, you've defined both `srcs` and `data` to point to your `media` label, and that is exactly the missing bit to have data available for execution of your `*_binary` rule. Because the `untar` rule returned `depset` of `files`, but those when used `data` directly would resolve to being empty.

If you replace this line in your rule definition:

```
return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([tree]))]
```

with:

```
return [DefaultInfo(runfiles = ctx.runfiles([tree]))]
```

You can then in your `BUILD` file say:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    data = [":media"],
)
```

Because `untar` rule now provides [`runfiles`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.1.0/skylark/lib/runfiles.html) of [`DefaultInfo`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/DefaultInfo.html). That `filegroup` wrapping and adding `media` through its `data` property has done that.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that everything inside the media folder has to be a header or a cpp while I have random media files `ERROR: Artifact '.../media.cpp/font.ttf' expanded from the directory artifact '.../media.cpp' is neither header nor source file.`

Comment: That is where handling it as an external dependency would have been beneficial as well: you provide `BUILD` file that makes sure you expose only the files that you need/want from the archive. Again, I do not know the specifics of your situation, but bringing the tarball in that ways at least on the face of it sounds like a clean way to go about it.

Comment: My tar.gz is generated by another rule, first fetch an external dependency, then do some preprocessing that generates the tar.gz. The tarball contains lots of files, so I was trying to avoid having to list them all.

Comment: So, if you have an external dep... and you need some (processed; other rule) inputs for your `cc_binary`, using tarball (with mixed content) to pass output of one rule to the other, sounds still a little more complicated then it should be. When you get your ext. dep, it sounds like whatever produces the inputs for `cc_binary` should do just that... and if you also want to have a tarball for publishing, that is a separate target (leaf node of the build tree for that)? Am I missing anything substantial?

Comment: Not sure I follow. So my setup is the following, I have an external repository with a bunch of encrypted files, I have a rule that decrypts them and produces a tar ball. With my setup works, but I was wondering if I could simplify it by removing the intermediate filegroup. Sure I could make the decrypt rule produce a folder directly but I would still need the intermediate file group. Thanks for all the help btw :)

Comment: Essentially you have to prepare your inputs for the `cc_*` rule(s) one way or the other. But from what you describe, it seems to be the external dependency (encrypted tarball) is essential the source of inputs. Hence, rather then having custom build rule as the `untar` in your example, it would seem meaningful to have a custom [`repository_rule`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#repository_rule) that fetches the (encrypted) tarball and processes it to expose it's content to `cc_*` (or any other rules, e.g. `pkg_tar` if you wanted to publish it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208807/discussion-between-ondrej-k-and-nsubiron).

Comment: hey @OndrejK. I'm curious if I do the similar thing but then would like to put extracted files back into pkg_tar I always get empty archive. Am I missing something or is it not working that way? Thanks